# Downloading images inside CSS files

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to download all the images from css files. The images are in the `url(https://www...image.png)` format

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents("global-61.css");
$path = 'found/';

preg_match_all('https:\/\/www.[^0-9]+.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)', $result, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($output as $item)
{ 
    copy($item, $path . basename($item));
}
?>
```

The links are from different websites--however I think my regex is not correct.  When I try to run the script it does not match any of the images.  What could be wrong here if the regex is okay? Hotlink protection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_match_all('/\bhttps:\/\/www\.[^0-9]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)\b/m'
```

You were missing the enclosing delimiters of the regex (/'s) and you need to tell it to match literal dot by escaping it using \ so it becomes the above.

Some improvements:

1. If you want to match hosts not having www, you could add `?` after www
2. As Dr. Kameleon suggested, you could also match both https and http quite easily

   `preg_match_all('/\bhttps?:\/\/(www)?\.[^0-9]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)\b/'`

Comment: You don't need `/m`, it only affects `^` and `$` which are not used.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes :

- Why just "https". You could search for both http/http : `http(s)?`
- Better not use `[^0-9]`, something like `[A-Za-z\-]+` would be better
- "." (the dot) must be escaped

So, what about something like :

`http(s)?:\/\/www\.[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.(png|jp(e)?g|gif)`